# Can anybody please help me run Aika Online on ubuntu?

Tags: wine, games

I can get till laucher but after that it doesn't respond.

I am attaching a screenshot. Everything got installed and I was able to successfully update it too, but it wont run and I keep getting some kinda message like "Too many users" Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Run the app with wine from terminal, and update your post with the output that wine would give. Without that it is hard to say what's the problem — perhaps some dll missing, or something…

Comment: Well, I tried almost everything. It seems maybe it doesn't support it's Security system(X-trap).

Comment: Hm… [Internet indeed says](https://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2011/03/msg00047.html) that X-Trap isn't supported because it works like a driver, and drivers in wine doesn't work. On the other hand, there mentioned Wow as an example of such game, but I remember WoW was working for me a few years ago. I'd advice you to look anyway at wine output, and to post it here.

Comment: Though yeah, [appdb says](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30500) indeed, that the game wasn't working because of X-Trap. Well, then there's indeed nothing we can do ☹ I'd report a bug to Aika developers or mailed them a message of a problem — that obviously wouldn't work, but to let them know the problem, and just for fun.

Comment: …and try to disable X-Trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did all my research and it seems X-trap isn't gonna work on Linux. So there's nothing that can be done for now e.e